# Selecting list elements depending if they contain sub-list elements

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have:

```
aa = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}

bb = {{4, 4}, {5, 5}}

cc = {{a, {1, 1}}, {b, {2, 2}}, {c, {3, 3}}, {d, {4, 4}}, {e, {5, 5}}, {f, {6, 6}}}
```

How can I select all elements form `cc` that contain all elements from `aa` as well as from `bb`?

The result should be:

```
{{a, {1, 1}}, {b, {2, 2}}, {d, {4, 4}}, {e, {5, 5}}}
```

Comment: ... if you've already assigned values to `a` and `b`, they will not show up in `c`.

Comment: sorry for the mistake ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`ContainsAny`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContainsAny.html).

```
Select[cc, ContainsAny[Join[aa, bb]]]
```

> ```
> {{a, {1, 1}}, {b, {2, 2}}, {d, {4, 4}}, {e, {5, 5}}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Noting J.M.'s observation in the comments, I redefined your lists as

```
aa = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
bb = {{4, 4}, {5, 5}};
cc = {{a, {1, 1}}, {b, {2, 2}}, {c, {3, 3}}, {d, {4, 4}}, {e, {5, 5}}, {f, {6, 6}}};
```

Then,

```
Cases[cc, {_, Alternatives @@ Join[aa, bb]}, {1}]
(* {{a, {1, 1}}, {b, {2, 2}}, {d, {4, 4}}, {e, {5, 5}}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Several methods in addition to `Cases` in @march's answer:

```
Select[cc, MemberQ[Join[aa, bb], #[[2]]] &]
Pick[cc,  MemberQ[Join[aa, bb], #[[2]]] & /@ cc]
DeleteCases[cc, _?(! MemberQ[Join[aa, bb], #[[2]]] &)]
```

> {{a, {1, 1}}, {b, {2, 2}}, {d, {4, 4}}, {e, {5, 5}}}

Answer (score 3):

```
Select[cc, MemberQ[Join @@ Thread[aa | bb]]]
```

> ```
> {{a, {1, 1}}, {b, {2, 2}}, {d, {4, 4}}, {e, {5, 5}}}
> ```

Comment: Also `ContainsAny[Join[aa, bb]]`.

Comment: @Edmund Nice, but unfortunately not available in version 10.1 which I use.

Comment: Can't you offer WRI some rep for an upgrade?

Comment: @Edmund: Please add your ContainsAny-Solution as an answer ... I like it very much.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible by using rules:

```
cc /. {s_Symbol, pair_List} /; !MemberQ[Join[aa, bb], pair] -> Nothing
```